# Sqlite ORDER BY group's count is slow

Tags: sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by

When I add an ORDER BY statement to my query it becomes very slow.

Here's my query without ORDER BY:

```
SELECT ClientIpAddress, Agentstring, Count(ClientIpAddress) AS Count FROM LogEntries
WHERE SiteIisId = 3 AND DateTime >= '13-09-2012 00:00:00'
GROUP BY ClientIpAddress, Agentstring
LIMIT 5
```

ET: 1ms

And now with ORDER BY:

```
SELECT ClientIpAddress, Agentstring, Count(ClientIpAddress) AS Count FROM LogEntries
WHERE SiteIisId = 3 AND DateTime >= '13-09-2012 00:00:00'
GROUP BY ClientIpAddress, Agentstring
ORDER BY Count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

ET: 294 ms

The table I'm querying contains 1.380.855 rows.

Here's the index I'm using:

```
CREATE INDEX "LogEntries_MostActiveClients" ON "LogEntries" ("ClientIpAddress" ASC, "Agentstring" ASC, "SiteIisId" ASC, "DateTime" DESC)
```

Using `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` Sqlite tells me it's scanning the table using my index and is using `TEMB B-TREE`for my Order By.

How can I overcome this problem? Obviously I can't index the `Count`, so what to do?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Please note that the comparison on `DateTime` doesn't work correctly because it doesn't start with the most significant field, the year. You should use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the index that is being used. Thanks for pointing out the DateTime issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are stepping through a result set, SQLite tries to compute as many values as possible *on the fly*.

So, in your first query, SQLite never needs to group all the address/agent values in the table; as soon as it has read the records of the first five `ClientIpAddress`/`Agentstring` combinations through some index, it can stop.

In your second query, this is not possible: all address/agent groups have to be completely computed before they can be sorted and the first five ones chosen.

The records in the temporary result to be sorted are already in the cache, and are smaller than the data in the original table, so I'd guess that most of the time is not spent sorting, but grouping.

If the sorting were the problem, and if you had an estimate of how large the five largest counts would be, you could try adding a `HAVING "Count" >= some_limit` clause to reduce the number of records to be sorted.

There's nothing you can do to avoid the grouping.
All you can try is to get small improvements with generic optimizations, such as:

- increase SQLite's [page cache](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) to the size of your working set; and
- create a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) to avoid having to do lookups in the table itself (you already have that).

Another way would be to precompute the values for this query: have a separate table with your `Count`, and update it whenever you add a log entry. This will make these updates slower, and you'll have to determine what granularity to use for timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately adding a `HAVING` statement only adds to the execution time (with or without `ORDER BY`). Do you have any suggestions how I can overcome the problem? It doesn't necessary have to be this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Test your application with the SQLite amalgamation found [here](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite3-20121009.zip).

Richard Hipp recently announced:

> We have recently made a number of significant enhancements to the query
>   optimizer in SQLite.  In particular, the latest code does a much better job
>   of recognizing when ORDER BY clauses can be satisfied by careful selection
>   of indices and scan orders and without having to do any sorting.  This
>   optimization can result in significant performance improves for queries
>   with large result sets.

The e-mail thread is [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Please-test-the-latest-SQLite-enhancements-td64718.html).

Comment: Those enhancement are only for cases where the result is already ordered due to some index or `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yes, you need to add an appropriate index if it isn't already there.